# Concatenate XML via Shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I have a shell script that is used for concatenating xml. the format on the xmls is the following:

```
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
  <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   ...
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   ...
   </ns2:Body>
</DataPDU>
```

the problem is that after running the shell for concatenating:

```
#!usr/bin/sh
ORIGIN_PATH="/backup/data/export/imatchISO"
HISTORY_PATH="/backup/data/batch/hist"
SEND_PATH="/backup/data/batch/output"
DATE=`date +%y%m%d`
LOG="/backup/data/batch/log/concatIMatch_"$DATE

echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") >> $LOG
echo "-----------------------------------------------------" >> $LOG
echo "-----------------------------------------------------" >> $LOG
echo "-----STARTING INTELLIMATCH FILES CONTACTENATION------" >> $LOG
echo "-----------------------------------------------------" >> $LOG
echo "-----------------------------------------------------" >> $LOG

echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Starting..." >> $LOG
echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Cambiando ruta de trabajo " $ORIGIN_PATH >> $LOG
cd $ORIGIN_PATH
echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Listando contenido previo al concatenado" >> $LOG
ls -lrt >> $LOG

echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Comenzando concatenado de ficheros 053"  >> $LOG
cat $ORIGIN_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053_* >> $SEND_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053.XML_$DATE 2>> $LOG

echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Historificando ficheros..."  >> $LOG
mv $ORIGIN_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053_* $HISTORY_PATH >> $LOG 2>> $LOG


if [[ $(ls -A $SEND_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053.XML_$DATE) ]]; then
    echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Ficheros 053 concatenados"  >> $LOG
        mv $SEND_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053.XML_$DATE $SEND_PATH/SWIFTCAMT053.XML 2>> $LOG
        exit 0
else
    echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - Â¡ERROR CON LOS FICHEROS 053 AL CONCATENAR!"  >> $LOG
        exit 1
fi

echo $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" - FIN"  >> $LOG
```

The final structure of the obtained file is:

```
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
    <ns2:Header>
    <ns2:Message>
    ...
    </ns2:Message>
    </ns2:Header>
    <ns2:Body>
    ...
    </ns2:Body>
    </DataPDU>
    <DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
        <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
        <ns2:Header>
        <ns2:Message>
        ...
        </ns2:Message>
        </ns2:Header>
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>
        </DataPDU>
    <DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
    <ns2:Header>
    <ns2:Message>
    ...
    </ns2:Message>
    </ns2:Header>
    <ns2:Body>
    ...
    </ns2:Body>
</DataPDU>
```

which is not valid, as it's duplicating the initial

> ```
> <DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
>   <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
> ```

if I manually remove these the xml file works, but what could I do to work this out with the shell script?

The expected XML I would need would be:

```
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
    <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

        <ns2:Header>
        ...
        </ns2:Header>
        
        <ns2:Body>
        ...
        </ns2:Body>

</DataPDU>
```

so, a single opening tag of DataPDU and all the content of all other files inside that one.

The issue with my current shell script is that is appending the content of one xml just under the previous one, when what  need is to have them all within the same XML tags.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit it and add the exact expected output based on your sample xml.

Comment: @JackFleeting  Sorry I didn't put an example of expected output, I have added one now, I hope it clarifies

Comment: All magnificent proof of the often repeated standard advice. Use a tool which understands XML to manipulate XML.

Comment: I don't have the option of a tool, I need to do it with a shell script :(

Comment: Calling tools is _what shell scripts do_. Everything you use from a shell script except those few facilities built into the shell itself is a tool -- `date` is a tool, `ls` is a tool, `grep` is a tool, etc. `awk` is a tool that happens to also be a general-purpose scripting language that can be used from shell. Similarly, `python` is also a tool that happens to be a general-purpose scripting language that can be used from shell, but one that happens to have good XML parsing libraries built in :)

Comment: If you're specifying only tools that _aren't_ general-purpose languages, then you get into things like `xmlstarlet`

Comment: BTW, your script has a shebang specifying `/usr/bin/sh`, but `sh` isn't guaranteed to support features like `[[`. Consider running your script through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: BTW, if you have a new enough version of bash to support `printf '%(...)T'`, you should be able to avoid all the (slow, expensive) calls to `date`. And think about opening your log file _just once_ when your script starts, instead of re-opening it at the start of every line where you want to write a log and then closing it at the end of that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would recommend using a proper XML utility per @tripleee in the comments, if you can use `awk` you may be able to use the following:

```
$ awk 'NR<3 {print} FNR>3 {print last} {last=$0} END{print}' *.xml
```

`NR<3 {print}` print the first two lines processed.

`FNR>3 {print last} {last=$0}` print lines 3 through n-1 of each file processed.

`END{print}` print the last line processed.

Output:

```
$ awk 'NR<3 {print} FNR>3 {print last} {last=$0} END{print}' *.xml
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
  <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m1
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b1
   </ns2:Body>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m2
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b2
   </ns2:Body>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m3
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b3
   </ns2:Body>
</DataPDU>
```

Contents of *.xml files:

```
$ cat *.xml
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
  <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m1
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b1
   </ns2:Body>
</DataPDU>
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
  <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m2
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b2
   </ns2:Body>
</DataPDU>
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
  <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m3
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b3
   </ns2:Body>
</DataPDU>
```

You could also place the `awk` command into a bash script that accepts 2 parameters: the source xml directory and the name of the file to hold the concatenated XML.

Script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

xml_dir="$1"
output_xml_file="$2"

awk 'NR<3 {print} FNR>3 {print last} {last=$0} END{print}' "$xml_dir/"*.xml > "$output_xml_file"
```

Script usage:

```
# before script is run the output.xml file does not exist
$ ls output.xml
ls: output.xml: No such file or directory

# execute the script passing 2 parameters
$ ./script /tmp/t_dir output.xml

# after script execution, the output.xml file now exists and contains the concatenated xml
$ ls output.xml 
output.xml
buck:t_dir buck$ cat output.xml 
<DataPDU xmlns:ns2="urn:swift:saa:xsd:saa.2.0">
  <ns2:Revision>2.0.13</ns2:Revision>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m1
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b1
   </ns2:Body>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m2
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b2
   </ns2:Body>
   <ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Message>
   m3
   </ns2:Message>
   </ns2:Header>
   <ns2:Body>
   b3
   </ns2:Body>
</DataPDU>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, yes, Sadly I can't use tools, one question, can this be put in a shell script? what I need is a way for a script to pick all .xml files in a path and then concatenate them as it shows here? so it will combine all .xml into a single one

Comment: maybe with a process  that removes the first 2 lines and last lines of all files, then concatenates them into a single file and add the first 2 lines (tags) and last line ( closing tag)  I think that would fix it, I'm working it how to do it with my very limited shell

Comment: You can put the `awk` command in a script if necessary.  The `*.xml` lists all files in the current directory with the '.xml' extension.  The `awk` command does precisely what you describe.

Comment: So this should be a single file containing your awk line? Sorry I'm super lost reading about it. Your output looks exactly as what I need but I dont know where to apply it (I need tongenerate the output xml file with the concatenated version)

Comment: See updated answer for `bash` script containing `awk` command.

Comment: thank you so much, this works great, I can't upvote it enough!